# Why is 365 an 8-bit number here?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, random-seed

Looking at the [sample code](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html) for the seeding of gfortran's random number generator, I was puzzled by the time conversion here:

```
call date_and_time(values=dt)
tms = (dt(1) - 1970) * 365_8 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 &
    + dt(2) * 31_8 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 &
    + dt(3) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 1000 &
    + dt(5) * 60 * 60 * 1000 &
    + dt(6) * 60 * 1000 + dt(7) * 1000 &
    + dt(8)
t = transfer(tms, t)
```

I was curious why the `365` and `31` had `_8` trailing. [Looking it up](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z400073662be/index.html), I found that this indicates an 8 bit integer. Why would that be used here? I understand that it's just a random seed, so it doesn't really matter, but why would you truncate or mod 365 to an 8 bit value, and not the other numbers? Is it just whimsy? Does anyone have some insight into this?

**UPDATE:** It turns out I was confused about _8 meaning 8 bits when actually it means 8 bytes, which I should have known. So yeah. Thanks for setting me straight on that.

Comment: unrelated but dt3 line appears to have an extra 60

Comment: hmm.. that error is right in the gnu fortran docs, and as is it *will* overflow 32 bits.

Comment: for the record the `60 60 60` error in the docs has been fixed. (now using `_int64` instead of `_8` as well )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not 8 **bit**, it is 8 **byte**.

Of course, 365 does not fit in 8 bits which should have set the alarm bells ringing.

Comment: +1 It is even in the reference the poster links to: " its use specifies the data size, in bytes". And back to school for more training in "reading" ;)

Comment: Shoot, that's right! Well, can I use the excuse that it's late? ha... I should downvote myself :P

I'll accept this after the appropriate mourning period, but any insight on why only 365 and 31 have that? Does that upconvert the rest of the product to 8 bytes as well?

Comment: Ok, what would be the correct thing to do here? Since this was just my mistake, no one would really learn from this, except maybe to read twice before coming to silly conclusions. I could salvage the question by only asking whether the type propagates to the others, which I would like to know, or I could flag it for deletion. It's not that I'm ashamed (though I am), but this question obviously doesn't contribute to the community. I don't ask many questions and I'd like for the few that I do ask to be useful. Would it be offensive if I flagged this for deletion?

Comment: Doesn't really bother me either way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the rest of my question, setting the one number in those products to an 8 byte integer causes the product to be 8 bytes as well, according to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z400073a2265/index.html). The first two terms are likely to be the only ones large enough to require this locally, and the others will be converted when they are summed. So that's why only 365 and 31 needed to be 8 bytes.